# Warning: "An expression which is the result of a ~ or << operation has not been cast to its essential type" - How to fix?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, misra

I' doing operation on bytes where I want to add an uint8 to the MSB of an existing uint32:

```
uint32 my_uint32;
my_uint32 = 0x00ffffffu;

my_uint32 = (uint32)(my_uint32) | ((uint8)(0x2u) << 24u));  // Add value 0x02 to the MSB of my_uint32 
my_uint32 = 0x02ffffffu    // This is what I get and is working so far
```

This is so far OK but I get the warning:

"*An expression which is the result of a ~ or << operation has not been cast to its essential type*"

I can get ride of the warning by doing:

```
my_uint32 = ((uint32)(my_uint32) | (uint8)((0x2u) << 24u)); // Here I'm doing the uint8 cast on the complete shift operation
```

But than this will not work. The result would be:

```
my_uint32 = 0x00ffffffu
```

Anyone idea how I can get away from the warning?

Comment: `2<<24` is too large for 8 bits, ie `(uint8)(2<<24) == 0`

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `uint8_t` and `uint32_t`, so maybe it's an artifact of your (custom?) types? Used `clang` which is normally pretty cantankerous and it's totally chill, zero warnings.

Comment: @tadman: Correct. But the 1st solution will work for sure. But how to get ride of the warning than?

Comment: Is that message from the compiler or from a MISRA tool? What is the size of `int` in your C implementation?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It is  a MISRA warning. Size of int is 32 bits,

Comment: Why do you use such a typecast if the result is converted again immediately? Why not use a more suitable type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `my_uint32 = (uint32)(my_uint32) | ((uint8)(0x2u) << 24u));` to `my_uint32 = my_uint32 | ((uint32) 0x2u << 24);`.

Essentially, the left operand of a shift should be converted to the desired result type, so that the shift is performed with that type. Casting it to `uint8` results in the shift being done with an `int` type, due to automatic promotion.

Comment: There's no need to cast to `uint32` either, unless the system uses 16 bit integers or need to be portable to such systems. The code was already MISRA compliant before all this casting begun.

Comment: @Lundin: There is no need with that particular value, but it might easily be edited to `0x80` or some macro in the future, and I figured MISRA and/or OP might want the form of the expression to be correct regardless of the operand being shifted.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
my_uint32 = (uint32)(my_uint32) | (uint32)((uint32)(uint8)(0x2u) << 24u));
```

But it could be shortened to this:

```
my_uint32 = (uint32)(my_uint32) | (uint32)((uint32)(0x2u) << 24u));
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make any sense and is certainly not required by MISRA-C either.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not really familiar with MISRA-C, but assuming `uint32` behaves like the standard `uint32_t`, the intention of the `(uint32)` cast on the left operand of `<<` is to ensure that the value being shifted has 32 value bits, and the intention of the `(uint32)` cast on the result of the `<<` operation is to comply with the given warning "An expression which is the result of a ~ or << operation has not been cast to its essential type" (whatever "essential type" means!).

Comment: If we ignore 16 bit `int` system, then this code does the following: `2u` = give me an unsigned int, no wait I changed my mind give me a uint8, no wait I changed my mind, give me an uint32 like I had from the start, shift, then convert from uint32 to uint32. All of which is senseless.

Comment: The warning is all about the incorrect uint8 cast which should simply be removed. I posted an answer explaining this.

Comment: @Lundin I think I get it now. The warning was issued because the result of the `<<` operator was not being cast to the type of the left operand of `<<`, which is the "essential type". The cast to `(uint8)` would serve a purpose if it was there to truncate its operand.

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that the operand `(uint8)(0x2u)` gets implicitly promoted to `int`, which is signed. Such promotions could cause subtle bugs.

Some old MISRA recommendation is to cast to the essential type afterwards, to ensure that the type of the expression stays consistent:

```
(uint32_t)(some_uint8_t << 24)
```

However, I would personally recommend to do this cast explicitly *before* the shift, so that you don't risk a type promotion to signed type then accidental shifts where you left shift bits into the sign bit or right shift with sign preserved (arithmetic shift) etc. That is, do this:

```
(uint32_t)some_uint8_t << 24
```

This is best practice on all 32 bit systems.

---

*However*, in your specific case the problem is here: `(uint8)(0x2u)`.

`2u` is already of type `unsigned int` which is already the right type for bit shift by 24. (Unless it's a system with 16 bit `int`, in which case the cast to `uint8` doesn't make any sense either.)

Just drop all the strange casts! This code is MISRA-C compliant:

```
my_uint32 = my_uint32 | (0x2u << 24u);
```

You *only* need to cast that operand if you need the code to work on 16 bit systems, in which case you can either do `(uint32)0x2u` or `0x2ul`, either is fine and MISRA compliant.